# How to remove UIViewControllers from hierarchy when segueing to new UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on an app that isn't quite "sequential" as far as how the views can go.

For instance, I can get into the following scenario where I segue to new views:

```
MatchesNavigationController -> ModalOptionsController -> ProfileViewController -> ModalOptionsController -> MatchesNavigationController -> MatchesNavigationController...
```

And so on and so forth.

In English, what is happening is the user is looking at their matches of people and is inside a text message with a user, then they click a modal options button from the toolbar and it pops up some options, and then the user wants to view their profile.  Then from the profile, they can click a button to make the same modal pop up, and from there can then go to the conversation with that person, which will again go back to the navigation controller where they are viewing the conversation.  And then from there they can click the options again, go to profile, and repeat...

But then if I'm on the `ProfileViewController` I can press "back" and that will segue "back" to the `MatchesNavigationController` via a custom RightToLeft segue that I wrote.

So I can get into instances where the ViewController stack starts to get large and large in this instance.

When I do this as well (go into this cyclical looking workflow), I have a Custom LeftToRight segue that I wrote because I want it to look like, to the user, that they are navigating in that direction.

How do I go about cleaning up the previous views in this cyclical type of navigation that you can get into here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `prepareForSegue:` call `self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` before segueing and it will release the current view controller from the stack before pushing the next one on.

Comment: But the views aren't `UINavigationControllers`.  They are just normal `UIViewControllers` and they don't have a `navigationController`, and the `UIViewController` class does not have a `popViewController` on it.

Comment: Ok try `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(self:completion:{})` But make sure its after the next one is presented.

Comment: `A better option for you would be to use a navigation controller for viewcontroller pushing and popping. And just hide the navigation bar using navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true`

Comment: I've tried the `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated` call and that does not work, it is still present in the view hierarchy.  If all else fails I may have to just use a navigation controller and do what you are saying, however I am trying to avoid rewriting a lot of code.  I would think there would be a basic way to remove viewcontrollers from the hierarchy but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I was playing around in the custom segue I wrote to see if I could do it there and I didn't have any luck last night.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more searching and digging, I realized what I was trying to do was more hacky than anything else, and I spent the weekend refactoring how my views are laid out and presented and just made everything inside of a `UINavigationController` and just pushed/popped everything how it should have been done, so I'm going to make this the accepted answer since this is really the way I should have done things from the beginning.